# WCF, Security and Certificates

Tags: wcf, authentication, wcf-security, certificate

I have a client/server WCF application that needs some sort of user authentication against a database.  The application (both client and server together) is being developed to be sold to dozens of customers, for use on their intranets.  We're not too worried about encrypting most of the data moving across the wire, except of course during authentication.

Thinking about WCF security, I keep coming back to the idea that we should be making use of x509 certificates. However, our customers will definitely not want to know about any of the details of having to apply for, purchase and install these certificates.

I'd like to know first of all what the preferred method is of implementing username/password authentication in this scenario.  If it will require using certificates, must the customer apply for their own certs from a trusted CA, or can we as the software provider generate certificates for the customer to use?

Really I'm looking for a best practice, with the least friction to our customers.

Thanks!

**Edit:**  I'm using NetTcpBinding, and my server is running as a Windows Service.

Answer (score 5):

So username/passwords does not require client certificates as I'm sure you're aware, it simply requires an HTTPS certificate on the server hosting the WCF service - once you have that you can happily use the standard username/password auth bits (WCF will not allow message based authentication without HTTPS).

If you wanted to head down the client certificate root you get the advantage of non-repudiation - you can be sure that the machine sending is who it says it is (unless someone has stolen the certificate, which is less likely than a username and password combination going walk about). You as the software provider could act as your own certificate authority and generate your own client certs (there are a few ways to do this depending on your infrastructure) but then you need to configure the clients to trust your root CA.

If the server and client are running in a domain environment you could use [transport security with Windows authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733089.aspx) (you're using tcp binding, so interoperability is out the window anyway!) The added bonus to this is the authentication is transparent and you don't need any certificates anywhere. If you want verfication of the server identity then [message security with Windows authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729709.aspx) will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks!  Something I forgot to mention is that I'm using NetTcpBinding.  Also, please remember that the server is being deployed to multiple customers too which is the main source of my problem regarding certs.

Answer (score 2):

I've got project in production which is similar to your scenario.  I have a Windows Service hosting endpoints via netTCPBinding and I used x509 certs... although in my case, the intent was to encrypt both the transport and message layers, as I was crossing over untrusted security boundaries.  I was less concerned with providing authentication/authorization other than requiring the certificate be present.

Similar to your intranet scenarios (I'm assuming), I had authority over the server and client machines at installation time... or at least could dictate some of the terms of installation.

Rather than purchase the x509 certs and burden the client with that expense, I opted to roll our own.  We set up one of our Win2003 servers to be a CA, issuing our own Certification Authority cert.  We then generated an x509 cert for the server, as well as individual x509 certs for the clients.

The client and server certs were installed on both clients and server (as appropriate) into the personal user store at the computer level.  We also installed our CA cert directly into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities section, thus making our client and server certs trusted.

Because I was less concerned with authentication/authorization, I don't know what to recommend as a best practice for dealing with binding certs to individual users and going more granular than machine-level (my solution was windows service to windows service communication -- completely unattended).  I would think you'd need a cert for each user, installing it into their personal user store in the certificates MMC.  The runtime implementation will be guided by how you configure WCF to do the cert lookup, so it should be fairly easy.

Throughout the process, I relied heavily on what I'd learned from this great CodeProject article: [Securing WCF Services with Certificates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcf_certificates.aspx?display=Print).  It walks you through generating/installing the certs.  The sample WCF applicatoin is IIS-hosted, but I was able to pretty easily translate the config sections from web.config to app.config.

In my case, I exposed the Web interface for requesting certificates in Win2003 to the web itself, so the client could request certificates directly in the future.  We have approval control, so it works well.  I haven't had a need to generate new certs yet, so I can't say how much friction that would entail.

Answer (score 1):

If your going to be crossing firewall boundaries then certificates are going to be your best solution. I don't know much about the specifics about applications for certificates or your application. Unfortunately, as far as i know, i think you will have to help them apply for certificates or they will have to do it their self unless they want to undertake in the process of installing their own certificate server. If the app will be internal then windows authentication will work and is VERY easy but if you think your going to have clients that user your application across firewall boundaries then you might as well invest the time in using certificates because certificates will work everywhere. Now there is something called federated security where you delegate the permission of authentication to another entity. I think this is used if say you have to domains and you want to delegate permission say of someone on another domain that is not on your domain to their domain but its pretty complex and my understanding of its very limited but by the sound of your requirements certificates is the way to go.

Security is not supposed to be easy :)